# In Gitlab CI/CD how to checkout another branch during the pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I would like to checkout to `dev` branch in a merge request pipeline that is opened for merging to `dev` with some other branch. I am going to check somethings in this job and then continue with some other jobs depending on the success of this one. Is it possible to do such thing or do I always have to work with the branch the pipeline triggered at?

I add the related part of the gitlab configuration

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

checksomething:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  environment:
    name: development
  before_script:
    - git checkout dev
  script:
    - !reference [.check-something-on-dev]
```

But I have this error:

````
$ git checkout dev
error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git```
````

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it was this easy:

```
    before_script:
    - git fetch origin dev
    - git checkout dev
```

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. I suppose the refspec did not fetch all the branches, forcing you to fetch the one you need.

Comment: it takes a lot of effort to figure out how to checkout a branch inside gitlab, they should document this better themselves. this fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try first a `git branch -avv` to see what branches are available through the original clone/checkout done the GitLab-CI job.

Depending on the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) used, the cloned repository might not reference any `origin/dev` branch, preventing the [guess mode of `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---guess) (or, for that matter, [of `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess), the more modern alternative to `checkout`) to work.

Comment: `git branch -avv` only returned `* (HEAD detached at 8ee41cf) 8ee41cf check branches 2` :/